How to format numbers in Google Sheets with Indian numbering style and display zero as a dash?
m working on a Google Sheets project where I need to format numbers in the Indian numbering system, which uses lakhs and crores, while also displaying zero values as a dash (-). I want to include the Indian Rupee symbol (₹) for non-zero amounts.
I have two custom number formats that work for different requirements:

For formatting numbers with ₹ and Indian comma style:
[$₹][>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0;[$₹][>99999]##\,##\,##0;[$₹]##,##0


For displaying zero as a dash:
₹0;-₹0;"-"



However, I need a way to combine these features so that:

Positive numbers are displayed with the ₹ symbol and Indian comma separators.
Negative numbers show a negative sign before the ₹ symbol.
Zero is displayed as a dash (-).
Numbers are rounded to the nearest whole number.

Question:
How can I create a single custom number format in Google Sheets that achieves all of the above?

There are several questions on StackOverflow (more than I want to list now) that address the "Google sheets Indian number format". Have you looked at these? Is there a specific aspect of your requirement that is not met by these?

I think you can only use either [condition];[condition];default or positive;negative;zero, not both in the same pattern. See Number format patterns. To get the formats you want, you will probably have to use a formula. See player0's contribution at Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets.

This question is similar to: Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Tedinoz  Yes I have checked all the questions there. This is bit different for the requirement: Zero should be displayed as a dash (-) and not ₹0

Your question is not possible and you may refer to @doubleunary's comment. If you want, you may file a feature request using this link.
